# Как итерироать объект, который наследуется от интерфейса? TypeScript

Tags: typescript

У меня есть объект tasks, который наследуется от интерфейса ITaskListState. Мне нужно пройти по всем полям оъекта и отфильтровать их по условию.

Tasks:

```
tasks: ITaskListState = {
    tasksToDo: new Array<ITaskItem>(),
    tasksInProgress: new Array<ITaskItem>(),
    finishedTasks: new Array<ITaskItem>(),
  }
```

Interface ITaskListState:

```
export interface ITaskListState
{
  tasksToDo:  Array<ITaskItem>,
  tasksInProgress: Array<ITaskItem>,
  finishedTasks:  Array<ITaskItem>,
}
```

Я пыталась реалировть фильтрацию так:

```
filterTasks(filteredTask: ITaskItem)
  {
    for (let key in this.tasks)
    {
      this.tasks[key] = this.tasks[key].filter((task: ITaskItem) => task !== filteredTask);
      console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Но во время компиляции я получаю ошибку:
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ITaskListState'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ITaskListState'.

Как я могу обойти эту ошибку компилятора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варианты решения.
1.

```
filterTasks(filteredTask: ITaskItem) {
  const keys = Object.keys(this.tasks) as Array<keyof ITaskListState>;

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    const key = keys[i];
    this.tasks[key] = this.tasks[key].filter((task: ITaskItem) => task !== filteredTask);
    console.log(key);
  }
}
```

2. 

```
filterTasks(filteredTask: ITaskItem)
  {
    let key: keyof ITaskListState;
    for (key in this.tasks)
    {
      this.tasks[key] = this.tasks[key].filter((task: ITaskItem) => task !== filteredTask);
      console.log(key);
    }
  }
```